# Is it possible to see a Teredo IPv6 address in IPv6 neighbor cache?

Tags: ipv6, ipv6-transition

Is it possible to see a Teredo address (from `2001::/32` block) in an IPv6 neighbor cache? For example, in the case of Junos, in the output of `show ipv6 neighbors`. As much as I tested, this is not possible because traffic leaving the Teredo client is already encapsulated in UDP/IPv4.

Comment: I don't think you will, as they aren't actually neighbors.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Do you mean that Teredo addresses are never configured on a physical interfaces and thus they are never a neighbor?

Comment: Teredo is a _tunnel_ and has no neighbors. Neighbors are other IPv6 speaking devices on the same link. Teredo has none, as the link is virtual and no other devices are on it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, I think I understand this the same way. At least in Linux using Miredo Teredo client, the `teredo` interface(which is actually a `tun` interface) gets the IPv6 address from `2001::/32` block and traffic destined to IPv6 addresses leaving the Teredo host are encapsulated to UDP/IPv4. So indeed, the interface with Teredo IPv6 address has no neighbors. Also, as much as I understand the Teredo relay part, then they announce the `2001::/32` prefix, but do not have any interfaces with addresses from `2001::/32` address block, i.e there should be no neighbors from `2001::/32`.

Comment: I think you should consider rewriting your comments to an answer, @MichaelHampton, so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't see Teredo addresses in the neighbor cache, because Teredo creates a virtual point to point link and therefore has no neighbors. A neighbor is another device (which, for this purpose, speaks IPv6) on the same Layer 2 link. But a Teredo connection has no such devices sharing its virtual link.

Comment: I wanted to make sure you saw [this](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/813/8499) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376865/3745413) as they directly to relate to [sf]. (By the way, I grew up in Austin, and my family still lives there. I was there on Thanksgiving, and I'm sure I will be back for Christmas, and maybe for my birthday that is four days later.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing teredo addresses in a neigbour cache then something is seriously misconfigured.

Teredo creates a virtual interface on the teredo client allowing it to communicate with other teredo clients and relays. This virtual interface is not an Ethernet-like interface, so it has no need for neighbour discovery.

Unlike with 6to4 teredo has no provision for running a network behind the teredo client. So teredo addresses should never be assigned to a real network segment and therefore should never appear in a neighbour cache.